# Why does a MOSFET enter saturation?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos, fet

From all my browsing, it has become clear that as drain-source voltage increases, we eventually reach saturation. Mathematically, Vds>Vgs-Vt is the condition we look at.
But when I try to understand it logically, we need a reverse bias at Vgs to attract minority carriers from substrate to form a channel. So now that the channel is formed, a drain source voltage gives rise to a current flow due to electrons. 
It also makes sense that Vds should produce a depletion region at one of source/drain and reduce depletion region.

But how would all this relate to channel widths, saturation and everything else that gives rise to saturation?

Comment: I am not an expert with MOSFET. But i will add few cents. at the onset of saturation channel width will become almost constant with less variation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused with the behavior of a Bipolar transistor.

For a BJT the Collector Base junction will be nearing forward bias to enter saturation mode.

Take note:

- for a BJT, saturation means that the transistor does **NOT** determine the collector current Ic. This happens when \$V_{ce} < V_{ce,sat}\$
- for a MOSFET, saturation means that the transistor **DOES** determine the drain current Id. This happens when \$V_{ds} > V_{ds,sat}\$

*we need a reverse bias at Vgs to attract minority carriers from substrate to form a channel* No that's not how the channel is formed.

Reverse bias means that there must be a PN junction, there is no junction involved for the gate. The gate is formed when (for an NMOS) the gate potential is higher than the substrate potential + Vthreshold. The positive voltage pulls the negative carriers (electrons) towards the gate oxide to form a channel.

[image]

This picture shows the situation when an NMOS is in saturation mode. Note how there is a **gap** (of length \$\delta\$) between the right end of the channel and the drain. The amount of current that can flow is determined by the shape of the channel, as long as \$V_{gs}\$ remains constant and there is at least some distance between the channel and the drain (\$\delta > 0\$) then the NMOS will remain in saturation.

Channel width and other parameters are indeed all related to saturation mode. It goes a bit too far to explain all the relations here. My advise to you is to think about what happens to the channel in the MOSFET when one parameter is changed like, an increase in \$V_{gs}\$ or a slightly longer transistor.

Comment: Still can't understand how in saturation Id is dependant on the transistor. The very definition of saturation means that something has reached  a peak value. Meaning that it should't depend on Vds.                                    As for the channel, shouldn't it stay uniform? Vgs frees up electrons in the substrate. And then Vds gets it to act as a wire. And even if there had a parity, wouldn't the right side have MORE free electrons?

Comment: *Meaning that it shoul't depend on Vds* And that's **correct**, but, there are other parameters like Vgs and size of the transistor. Those do influence Id in saturation mode. OK, I cannot dynamically change the size of the transistor but i **can** change Vgs. Lowering Vgs will make the channel smaller and decrease Id.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it. the gate voltage produces attracts valence electrons and not free electrons. Vds essentially releases them, leaving behind uncompensated cations. So eventually Vds says, "I have only these many electrons to work with." meaning that there is as saturation and a decreased channel length. But isn't it likely that increases in vds would increase the rate of electron flow as well? Or is it just that without a channel, there is only so much that current can grow? Unless Vgs goes up and releases more free electrons.

Comment: Uhm, not really, the gate does attract free electrons. But really, what the carriers form the channel is irrelevant. What is relevant is Vgs as it will determine the shape of the channel. That shape then determines the current.

Comment: time to drop out of college

Comment: You should not give up that easily! You're very close to the AHA! moment so stick with it. Discuss the above with a fellow student and that does not need to be someone who understands it all. For sure it took me a while to grasp all this. But believe me, it gets better when you master all this nonsense ;-)

Comment: thanks for your help, But I think I need one last hint before the logic is clear. Is the "Channel" free electrons or uncompensated anions. I'm guessing uncompensated anions, but am not a hundred percent sure.

Comment: It depends on PMOS or NMOS. An NMOS is made in a P-doped substrate. Drain and Source are then **N**-doped (and that's why it's an **N**MOS). To make a conducting connection between D and S we then need **N**egative carriers (i.e. the channel consists of **electrons**). To attract these we need a positive voltage (with respect to the substrate) at the gate. Make a side-view drawing of an NMOS to better understand it.

Comment: A PMOS is made in a N-doped substrate. Drain and Source are then **P**-doped (and that's why it's a **P**MOS). To make a conducting connection between D and S we then need **P**ositive carriers (i.e. the channel consists of **holes**). To attract (actually repel the electrons) these we need a negative voltage (with respect to the substrate) at the gate. Make a side-view drawing of an PMOS to better understand it. Really, it is not that hard.

Comment: So NMOS channel: electrons, PMOS channel: holes. Now electron mobility (how quick they are to move) is about 3x higher than hole mobility. That makes an NMOS transistor faster (and have more more transconductance) than a similar size PMOS transistor.

Comment: I think I got it. when we have an NMOS, the positive voltage repels holes and attracts free electrons. The electrons form a channel and are more mobile than the anions that are formed by hole repulsion.

Comment: So as we  supply Vds, both anions and electrons are attracted towards the drain(where the positive probe is connected), but due to mobility differences, the electrons move faster. Initially, the channel works fine and acts as a conductor. But soon, Voltage at drain is high enough to attract the anions as well, which clogs up the channel(not scientific terms). This means that even if we increase Vds, we have less luck with the channel and current stays constant.

Comment: mathematically, the voltage at gate(Vgs-Vthreshold) needs to be great than Vds to ensure that anions aren't attracted into clogging up one side and can stay uniform. Which is mathematically seen as Vds>Vgs -Vt for saturation

Comment: Yes, you got it! Regarding the last comment: how I see it is that the Vds "stretches out" between drain and source. So if Vds = 4 V then somewhere in between there's a point where the potential under the gate oxide is 2 V. Only when the voltage between such a point (under the gate oxide) and the gate itself is > Vt can there be a channel. So in saturation, there's a channel between source and that point. And no channel between that point and the Drain. For an NMOS with Vt=1V and Vgs = 3V then that point would be at Vgs-Vt = 2 V.